# How to dispaly full page image in ionic app

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using ionic tab template & in my app there is a page with full image, that image getting form json response.

Here is the my html code

```
<ion-content class="padding">
    <img src="{{img}}" alt="" class="full-image">
</ion-content>
```

My question is how to handle image resolution in different devices.
If any one have idea please share with me

Comment: [this](http://codepen.io/rdelafuente/pen/tJrik) might be help.!

Comment: You dont have to worry about resolution, CSS can fit it for you. Take a look at this link: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: thanks css tricks is very useful for my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to handle images in different devices and I did this in my controller:

```
 $scope.width=$window.innerWidth*0.65;//65% of the width
//change the percentage to fit your goals

 $scope.height=$window.innerHeight*0.65; //65% of the height
//change the precentage to fit your goals
```

and used it like this in the .html :

```
<img ng-src={{image.src}} height={{height}} width={{width}} />
```

I don't know if this is the best way, but it works!